# How to change the height of an individual cell in a datagridview?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, c++-cli, clr

I would like to know how you would change the height of a cell without affecting the whole row. I'm making a timetable form and I need to change the height of a cell depending on the amount of time the event takes.

I'm making this in a clr project and using C++

Comment: It is a *grid*, making the height of a cell larger inevitably must affect the entire row.

Comment: Oh ok. Is there then any way to change the colour of a row instead? I tried using Color->Red but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dataGridView1->Rows[0]->Cells[0]->Style->BackColor = Color::Red;

sets the background colour of the first cell on the first row to red.

Change dataGridView1 to whatever your datagridview is called and set the row and column values as you need them.

You will probably also have to add: - using namespace System::Drawing;

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Style.BackColor instead

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells)
     cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: How would you do that in c++? Color->Red only gives me errors

Comment: Reference System.Drawing and see if it fixes your problem